# Python code runs fine from command line, but won't work from IDLE

Tags: python, command-line, usb, python-idle

I've found a lot of people having the reverse issue, but haven't yet found a question that involves IDLE not being able to run something that runs fine from the command line. I'm using a new module that I haven't used before that uses one .pyd file and one .dll, and involves a device that connects through USB. I sadly can't post in-depth code snippets since this is copyrighted code, but if anyone knows where to start on a problem like this I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you are receiving any kind of error **tracebacks** you should post those.

Comment: Or at least put together some of your own code that illustrates the problem, if you can't post the code you are working on directly.

Comment: Sadly not getting a traceback, it just freezes up and won't connect with the usb device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE swaps out the sys.stdout and sys.stderr objects at the Python level this causes issues with some pyd modules. Try using another debugger.